# How do I get a list of all C++ projects hosted on Github?

Tags: github, github-api

How do I get a list of all the C++ projects hosted on Github quickly? The Github API only allows 5000 requests per hour, so it's inefficient to query all the over 100 million repositories and filter out all the C++ projects from the list, as it would take at least 2.2 years.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [BigQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigQuery) instead, as in "[Query Github Data Using BigQuery](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bigquery-github/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)"

That would allow to retrieve the kind of volume you are after.

Or you can try a [GraphQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphQL) approach, as in "[Using Github’s GraphQL to retrieve a list of repositories, their commits and some other stuff](https://medium.com/@fabiomolinar/using-githubs-graphql-to-retrieve-a-list-of-repositories-their-commits-and-some-other-stuff-ce2f73432f7)".

Comment: BigQuery is a paid search and therefore not the preferred solution.
That blog post doesn't answer the question how to list all the 1 million C++ repositories that are available on Github.

Comment: @Jover That post lists the two known alternative to query such a massive number of elements from GitHub. And BigQuery has a free tier (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#free-tier)